# SAS - referring to a folder based on date

Tags: sas

In my SAS code I would like to refer to an existing folder based on the date value (LADE_DATUM) that I declare with a prompt. From this date I define LADE_JAHR and LADE_MONAT:

```
%let LADE_JAHR = %sysfunc(year("&LADE_DATUM"D));

%let LADE_MONAT = %sysfunc(month("&LADE_DATUM"D));
```

Based on these two variables I would like to refer to some existing folders (importpfad) that look like:
2020-09, 2020-10, 2020-11, 2020-12, etc.

This is the code:

```
data _null_; 

if &lade_monat < 10 then a = '0'; else a = ''; 

call symput('a',a);


%let importpfad = /folderx/Input_Files/**&lade_jahr/&lade_jahr.-&a.&lade_monat**/;
```

The problem is, if a = '' then the folder it refers to looks like "2020- 10" instead of "2020-10".

So there is a space between that I don't want to have.

If a is between 1 and 9, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell `%SYSFUNC()` you want the month number generated with the `Z` format instead of the default `best` format.

```
%let LADE_MONAT = %sysfunc(month("&LADE_DATUM"D),Z2.);
%let importpfad = /folderx/Input_Files/&lade_jahr/&lade_jahr.-&lade_monat/;
```